# HTML: why is bootstrap carousel not working?

Tags: html, github, twitter-bootstrap-3, atom-editor, favicon

Getting straight to the point. When I put in the bootstrap code, my website shows no image, no carousel.

I am fairly new to HTML and webdesign in general. I have looked a w3 guides, bootstrap's website, but, I can't get the image to show up. I just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I use OS X. I am using my [github](https://github.com/acetousk/acetousk.github.io) repository.

Comment: Try adding jquery and bootstrap.js to your code

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you need to add Bootstrap's JavaScript CDN and jQuery CDN You can find both of them at the links provided below. Try placing the script tags at the bottom of your HTML, just above the closing body tag, so that the scripts load after your HTML.

You can get Bootstrap JS CDN here http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

And jQuery here https://code.jquery.com/